# XNU Max thread count

Tags: multithreading, macos, process, kernel

How to know about the maximum thread count in Darwin kernel space?
Is it unlimited?
I mean the kernel_task with PID 0.

I use the Mac OS X 10.6.5

```
$ uname -a
Darwin foo.bar 10.6.0 Darwin Kernel Version 10.6.0: Wed Nov 10 18:13:17 PST 2010; root:xnu-1504.9.26~3/RELEASE_I386 i386
$
```

Видимо никто не знает...

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is sysctl - kern.num_threads is what you are looking for (typical value is 10240).

Hope this answer (a year or so later) helps,

TG